# How to write query in CakePHP format?

Tags: php, cakephp

Please check my query. I need to convert it into to cakephp format.

```
SELECT category,user_id 
FROM `products` 
WHERE status=1 
GROUP BY category  
ORDER BY COUNT(category) DESC
```

**CakePHP**

```
$conditions=array('Product.status'=>1)
$fields = array('Product.category','Product.user_id');
$groups = array('Product.category');

$order = array('COUNT'=>array('Product.category DESC'))

$this->Product->find("all",array('conditions'=>$conditions,'group'=>$groups, 'order'=>$order, 'limit'=>10));
```

Above CakePHP query i am getting null result. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$conditions=array('Product.status'=>1)
$fields = array('Product.category','Product.user_id','COUNT(Product.category) as categoryCount');
$groups = array('Product.category');

$this->Product->find("all",array('fields'=>$fields,'conditions'=>$conditions,'group'=>$groups,'order'=>array('categoryCount DESC'), 'limit'=>10));
```